# How parse JSON data in Codeigniter 3

Tags: json, codeigniter

In my project, using Codeigniter 3, I have a controller that get a JSON object in response from an API call, I'm trying to parse the JSON object but I'm not able to figure out to the access to each data.

The JSON object is the following:

```
{
    "ok":true,
    "result":
    {
        "message_id":9,
        "sender_chat":
        {
            "id":-11234567899,
            "title":"Sandbox",
            "username":"JustDummyUsername",
            "type":"channel"
        },
        "chat":
        {
            "id":-11234156789,
            "title":"Sandbox",
            "username":"JustDummyUsername",
            "type":"channel"},
            "date":1629538111,
            "text":"Lorem ipsum dummy text",
            "entities":
            [
                {
                    "offset":0,
                    "length":26,
                    "type":"bold"
                },
                {
                    "offset":112,
                    "length":22,
                    "type":"text_link",
                    "url":"xxxxxxxxxx"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I try, for example, the following code to get the message_id value

```
$json = $this->get_json_data();
$message_id = $json->result->message_id;
```

or

```
$json = $this->get_json_data();
$message_id = $json[0]->result->message_id;
```

but in both cases I get an error

```
Trying to get property 'result' of non-object
```

What's wrong?
Thanks a lot for any feedback.

EDIT: Silly me...I forgot json_decode().
Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Silly me. I forgot to json_decore the returned data